# Is it possible to copy hyperlinked text to the clip board and write it back into a textbox?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyautogui

I am automating a task that is performed on the web using chromedriver, selenium, and pyautogui. I am able to open up a pop up on a web page (that i believe uses javascipt). I am then able to delete the existing text in the textbox and write new text to it and click send. (Please excuse any ignorance, as I am very new to programming in general. This is actually an expansion/edit of my very first python script/program, something that actually works lol.)

When I initially open the pop up to write a message, a template exists in the text box. It contains an important and unique hyperlink. I want to extract this, and then delete all the content in the text box, and write a new message that includes that specific link. This task will be automated multiple times, and the link is unique based on who the message is going to.

I have tried finding the hyperlink by xpath and a couple of other things but I keep getting various errors. One thing I will note, and excuse my lack of knowledge, but the xpath is very different looking on this site. Again, I believe this is because of javascript. Here is an example xpath for the hyperlink:

```
//*[@id="clientEmailFormOneModal"]/div[3]/div[11]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a
```

I've used xpath on this site for other things but when those divs come into play, things get weird.

Here is my current function for this specific task:

```
def email_estimate():
    driver.find_element_by_id('hlEmailInvoiceOrEstimate').click() #clicks button on page to reveal the 'send an email' pop up
    time.sleep(1.9)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('trumbowyg-editor').click() #clicks into the textbox on the pop up
    time.sleep(1)
    payLink = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="clientEmailFormOneModal"]/div[3]/div[11]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a') #my attempt at finding the hyperlink by xpath and saving it as a variable
    time.sleep(.5)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('trumbowyg-editor').clear() #clear the content of the textbox
    message_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('trumbowyg-editor')
    message_box.send_keys('hey', contactName, 'here is the link to pay:', payLink) #Write message including the contact name which was pulled in a step before this and works as expected, and the hyperlink, which does not work
    time.sleep(30)
    print("Followed up on estimate "+ str(j) + ". Contact: " + contactName) #clicks the send button to send the message
    time.sleep(1.85)
```

You can see the expected results written as comments for step in the code above. What actually happens is a Traceback and TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/automation/WIP/Payment FollowUps/payments.py", line 77, in <module>
    email_estimate()
  File "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/automation/WIP/Payment Follow Ups/payments.py", line 33, in email_estimate
    message_box.send_keys('hey', contactName, 'here is the link to pay:', payLink) #, contactName, payLink
  File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\automation\WIP\Payment Follow Ups\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
TypeError: sequence item 32: expected str instance, WebElement found
```

Answer (score 0):

`payLink = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="clientEmailFormOneModal"]/div[3]/div[11]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a')`

this one returns **webelements**. Which you want to concatenate with strings:

`message_box.send_keys('hey', contactName, 'here is the link to pay:', payLink)`

Which does not work, hence the `expected str instance, WebElement found`.

Extract the value from the webelement like `payLink[0].get_attribute("href")`.